# Can we use thread in servlet? as Servlet is its self a thread

Tags: servlets

can we use thread in servlet? if yes then how? Servlet is its self a thread and it spawns a thread for each new request. Then also i have confusion about this concept. 
please recommend me good sites for servlet and jsp

Comment: Thank you for your answer : @Serge Ballesta and Divide by Zero.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes you can**, If you have developed in `Java` before( *which i think you have*) then you should know that `main()` itself is a thread that spawns other threads if you use multithreading in your project.So there are no issues regarding this.Every thread can start some other `thread`.So `servlets` can do the same too. 
Regards

Comment: Please suggest me good sites for learning Java JSP and Servlets

Comment: Murach's jsp and servlets is the best and simplest of all..google it

Answer (score 0):

You can use threads in servlet. But a servlet is not a thread. It is an object which has methods. Servlet object are instanciated by a Java EE server (Glassfish, JBOSS, TomcatEE, etc.) or a servlet container (Tomcat). The container creates threads to deal with requests and in those threads it calls the servlet methods.

So you can create other threads in servlet methods, but you must know that the servlet object itself is shared between all threads created by the server => be careful in you try to use instance variables : they will be shared by all threads.

Comment: Please suggest me good sites for learning Java JSP and Servlets